# Form downloads same ZIP over and over

Tags: php

Thanks to the users community on this forum, I wrote a very simple web form that allows my user to view text files from within their Internet browser.

I have now two functions whereby the text files returned by the search are compressed into a ZIP. Here's my code

```
    function getFilesFromSite() { 
     $result = null; 
     $ZIPresult = null;
     if (empty($_POST['DBSite'])) { return null; } 
     $mydir = MYDIR;  
     $dir = opendir($mydir); 
     $DBSite = $_POST['DBSite']; 
     $getfilename = mysql_query("select filename from search_table where site='" . $DBSite . "'") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) { 
     $filename = $row['filename']; 
     $result .= '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '" target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>'; 
     $ZIPresult .= basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename.' ';
    }

    if ($result) {
    $result = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Search Results.</td></tr> $result</table>";
    shell_exec("/bin/rm -f SearchResult.zip;/usr/bin/zip -9 SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ." > /dev/null ");

    //header for forced download
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
    $fileName = 'SearchResult.zip';
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($fileName));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');

    ob_start(); // Starts output buffering.
    readfile($fileName); // "Outputs" the file.
    $content = ob_get_flush(); // Grabs the output and assigns it to a variable.
    print base64_encode($content);
    }

    function getFilesFromError() { 
//Just a copy paste from above with different input parameter...
    }
```

The problem is that the ZIP file with the contents from whatever search was done first gets downloaded over and over again. For instance, the results from getFilesFromSite() will always get downloaded even though I did a search with getFilesFromError() afterwards.

I suspect my headers are incorrectly set but I am not sure where.

PS: The new ZipArchive() library/class is not available on our production environment so I chose to use the Unix utility ZIP instead.

Comment: Is your script actually executing fully? In other words, are you getting any errors along the way? My guess is that your `shell_exec` call might be running into a file permissions error once SearchResult.zip is created.

Comment: don't copy-paste code like that, use a loop

Comment: you header says the data is binary, but you base64 it

Comment: are you using error reporting? try enabling E_ALL and E_STRICT

Comment: @user309483: Enabled E_ALL ; no error shown in error.log ; The reason why I use base64 encoding is because the ZIP file would initially get corrupted. Using base64 fixed this. Added ob_end_clean() but no change.

Comment: ob_start/readfile/ob_get? Why even bother? `echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($content));` even though you should NOT be base64 encoding the output, let alone buffering it in php memory.

Comment: if you base64 encode it, you have to let the client know somehow, so they can decode it. what kind of data corruption did you get? maybe you can upload one of the corrupt files somewhere. there might be an error message in it? did you check for that?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you're open to SQL injection with that code.  You can't assume your $_POST data came from your form.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php explains the problem and how to avoid it

Comment: @user309483: when I downloaded my ZIP from my server using FTP, the file was fine, not corrupted. When I downloaded it from my browser,  it was corrupted. Base64 took care of that. I could not see if there was an error message in it.

Comment: You can see if there is an error message, just search for "Warning" or "Error". Also, how is the client supposed to know that it is base64 encoded unless you tell the client that it is? Also, the file isn't a valid zip file if it's base64 encoded.

Comment: If there is an error, and you base64 the output, you obviously have to decode it before you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Base64 was actually not working for reasons well stated here. Instead, I turned `zlib` compression off and reverted back to using binary as output format. Finally, I set `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` in my header. Everything is working fine now ;  here's my code:

```
function getFiles() {
     ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');  
     $result = null;
     $ZIPresult = null;
     $cleanup = null;
     $output = null;
     $fileName = null;
    //remove old zip if any
     $cleanup = shell_exec("/bin/rm -f SearchResult.zip");
     error_log("SHELL OUTPUT=>" . $cleanup, 0);
     //test
     if (empty($_POST['DBRIDs'])) { return null; }
     $mydir = MYDIR; // set from the CONSTANT 
     $dir = opendir($mydir);
     $DBRIDs = $_POST['DBRIDs'];
     $getfilename = mysql_query("select /*! SQL_CACHE */ filename from automation where rid in (" . $DBRIDs . ")") or die(mysql_error());
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) {
     $filename = $row['filename'];
     $result .= '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '" target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>';
     $ZIPresult .= basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename.' ';
    }

    if ($result) {
    $result = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Search Results.</td></tr> $result</table>";
    $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/zip SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ." ");
    error_log("SHELL OUTPUT=>" . $output, 0);
    $fileName = 'SearchResult.zip';
    error_log("ZIP FILENAME=>" . $fileName, 0);

    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    //header for forced download
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileName));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($fileName);
        exit;
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }
```

Thanks to all for taking the time!!